# Sending mail with Mandrill and Rails failing after awhile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using a rake task to send mass emails out to all of my users. The task runs fine for awhile, but then I encounter this error:

`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed:`

Here is my setup in `production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port      => 587,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  :password  => ENV['MANDRILL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :domain => 'mydomain.com'
}
```

It's odd because I can send one-off emails just fine, and my mass mailer works for a couple of hours before failing.

Thoughts?

Rails 4.1.5 hosted on Heroku

Comment: Are you reached Mandrill limits (msg/hour or msg/month)?

Comment: @roxane I have plenty of msg/mo. As far as msg/hr, Mandrill says it will queue the messages until the next hour rolls around.

Comment: What did Mandrill support say about this issue? Have you tried using the API instead of SMTP?

Comment: Still in contact with support, they went away for the weekend and haven't gotten back yet. SMTP has been working great for me for a couple of months, unsure why the sudden change in performance